# how to transfer information to django by XMLHttpRequest GET method?

Tags: javascript, django, xmlhttprequest

Here is my js code:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('get', 'test');
request.send("{'name':'yixuan'}");
```

and in django:

```
def httptest(request):
    name = request.GET.get('name')   # name is none
    body = request.body              # body is empty ( b'' )
```

I can not get any information in django. Is the type wrong here or is the request head not setting?

Comment: We need more code here, and a precise description of the problem. At the very least, you need to send your Ajax to a URL, which your Django backend has listed in its `urls.py` and sends to the appropriate view function. Also, the function you have there doesn't actually return a response, unless there's more code you haven't shown.

Comment: @RobinZigmond there is a response, if I use POST method, I can get the information, but similarly, GET didn't. So, I think the problem is in the code I listed above. You don't have to worry about other places;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GET requests don't have a body. Your parameter to `request.send` is ignored, as documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send).

Either use a POST request, or add the data in the querystring format and append it to the URL:

```
request.open('get', 'test?name=yixuan');
```